# Setting background RGB value to invisible for multiple rasters in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, symbology

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

I need to set my background rgb value of 255,255,255 to transparent. In the layer-Properties Windows > Symbology I can do it for one layer, but can I batch set this, or use ArcPy?

I have to do it for around 300 layers.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that I can do it for an mxd document by going to :

Tools > ArcMAP-Options > Raster > RasterLayer > Background value

All Raster layers that are then subsequently added will receive the defined background color.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way that you can do this for existing layers in batch or via ArcPy.

However, there is an ArcGIS Idea called [ArcPy.Mapping - Support Layer Symbology Property Modifications](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008FolAAE) that looks like it would meet your requirement so I recommend that you vote for that.

```
Develop arcpy.mapping to support layer symbology modifications.

Examples include:

1. Changing ... colour (rgb and cmyk input values), size, font properies of single symbol
```

Answer (score 0):

The option of setting the Raster Display properties at the .aprx level also works in ArcGIS Pro.  Way better than doing it individually!